# Slack: How to be notified about new activity via email?

Tags: notifications, slack, microsoft-teams, slackbot, slack-integration

**TLDR:** In the Slack options, I can select to be notified about direct messages and mentions. How can I be notified about all new activity via email?

**Long version:**
I want to keep track of what happens in a Slack for work that I'm part of. It's a Slack team (is that how it's called?) with several sub channels, but not my main working environment (my company uses Microsoft Teams). Often weeks pass by without any activity in it. But then when there is activity, I want to know about it.

I don't want to install Slack on my computer (I use many computers at work) or on my private phone, nor keep the browser tab open all the time. The feature I'm looking for is to be notified via email whenever somebody posts something on Slack. Alternatively, being notified on Microsoft Teams would also be okay.

Is this possible? If it's not possible over the Slack options directly, is there some other (free) way to achieve this?